# Chrome 29 Facebook double login issue

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, facebook

Ever since Chrome updated to 29.0.1547.57 I have been having a problem with logging into Facebook. After going to www.facebook.com, writing in the login/pass click Log In, login and pass information dissapear and I have to write them in again. After doing so, and clicking Log In it takes me to *Sorry, your request could not be processed. Please try again.* page although I can go to my homepage or wherever (am logged in).

Is anyone else having similar problems?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I've noticed it too. After first logging in you're logged in, you have to refresh the page though (i.e. no need to log in for the second time). No solution for that yet. Looks like fb/chrome bug.

Comment: I see. Thought it was a problem maybe on my machine, but I've just tried it on another one, and same thing occurs. Interesting for such a "big" (chrome+fb - hardly an unused "combination") bug to go unfixed.

Comment: Removing facebook cookies helped, at least for now. Found here: http://blog.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=4780200397841&referer=related

Comment: Unfortunately, it helped only for a short period of time...